# Convert skipgrams to count matrix

Tags: python, machine-learning, text, nlp, nltk

I have a paragraph and would like to compute the co-occurrence matrix of words given a fixed window size.

```
a='Apply singular value decomposition to obtain word embeddings and compare with word2vec'.split()

list(skipgrams(a,n=2,k=4))
```

Output is a list of tuples

```
[('Apply', 'singular'), ('Apply', 'value'), ('Apply', 'decomposition'),...]
```

How can I use this skipgram result to convert to co-occurrence matrix?

Is there any existing functions or libraries I can use? (i.e. not create zero matrix and for loop each tuple). Seems countvectorizer is for ngrams..

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite the `analyzer` argument in `CounterVectorizer`, e.g.

```
from functools import partial 

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk.util import skipgrams

skip4_bigrams = partial(skipgrams, n=2, k=4)

def my_analyzer(text):
    return skip4_bigrams(word_tokenize(text))


v = CountVectorizer(analyzer=my_analyzer)

x_train = ['Apply singular value decomposition to obtain word embeddings and compare with word2vec',
           'This is another sentence with singular word thingy']

v.fit(x_train)

print(v.vocabulary_)
```

[out]:

```
{('Apply', 'singular'): 2,
 ('Apply', 'value'): 4,
 ('Apply', 'decomposition'): 0,
 ('Apply', 'to'): 3,
 ('Apply', 'obtain'): 1,
 ('singular', 'value'): 47,
 ('singular', 'decomposition'): 43,
 ('singular', 'to'): 46,
 ('singular', 'obtain'): 44,
 ('singular', 'word'): 48,
 ('value', 'decomposition'): 54,
 ('value', 'to'): 57,
 ('value', 'obtain'): 56,
 ('value', 'word'): 58,
 ('value', 'embeddings'): 55,
 ('decomposition', 'to'): 23,
 ('decomposition', 'obtain'): 22,
 ('decomposition', 'word'): 24,
 ('decomposition', 'embeddings'): 21,
 ('decomposition', 'and'): 20,
 ('to', 'obtain'): 52,
 ('to', 'word'): 53,
 ('to', 'embeddings'): 51,
 ('to', 'and'): 49,
 ('to', 'compare'): 50,
 ('obtain', 'word'): 38,
 ('obtain', 'embeddings'): 36,
 ('obtain', 'and'): 34,
 ('obtain', 'compare'): 35,
 ('obtain', 'with'): 37,
 ('word', 'embeddings'): 65,
 ('word', 'and'): 63,
 ('word', 'compare'): 64,
 ('word', 'with'): 67,
 ('word', 'word2vec'): 68,
 ('embeddings', 'and'): 25,
 ('embeddings', 'compare'): 26,
 ('embeddings', 'with'): 27,
 ('embeddings', 'word2vec'): 28,
 ('and', 'compare'): 10,
 ('and', 'with'): 11,
 ('and', 'word2vec'): 12,
 ('compare', 'with'): 18,
 ('compare', 'word2vec'): 19,
 ('with', 'word2vec'): 62,
 ('This', 'is'): 6,
 ('This', 'another'): 5,
 ('This', 'sentence'): 7,
 ('This', 'with'): 9,
 ('This', 'singular'): 8,
 ('is', 'another'): 29,
 ('is', 'sentence'): 30,
 ('is', 'with'): 32,
 ('is', 'singular'): 31,
 ('is', 'word'): 33,
 ('another', 'sentence'): 13,
 ('another', 'with'): 16,
 ('another', 'singular'): 14,
 ('another', 'word'): 17,
 ('another', 'thingy'): 15,
 ('sentence', 'with'): 41,
 ('sentence', 'singular'): 39,
 ('sentence', 'word'): 42,
 ('sentence', 'thingy'): 40,
 ('with', 'singular'): 59,
 ('with', 'word'): 61,
 ('with', 'thingy'): 60,
 ('singular', 'thingy'): 45,
 ('word', 'thingy'): 66}
```